# Mock settings in Web.conf with moq

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3, unit-testing, moq

I am using `VisualStudio.TestTools` for unit-tests in my MVC3-application. The file `/Web.conf` contains a custom configuration which value `"false"` I cant get in my controller by `ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["DisableCheckboxes"];`:

[image: screenshot web.conf]

That works well on productive, but not in unit-tests. The value is `"null"`:

[image: result of appsettings]

How can I use the framework Moq to Mock the settings in `/Web.conf`?

Comment: You probably have to copy those config settings into the config file for your test project. The test project will not access the web site's `web.config`.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but that doesn´t solve the problem - same behaviour: null.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You are better off if you abstract the config file reading, and inject this abstraction into your class, instead of using directly `ConfigurationManager`. Then for your tests you can mock the abstraction.

Create a `IConfigurationReader` interface:

```
public interface IConfigurationReader
{
   string GetConfigSetting(string settingName);
}
```

The real implementation will use `ConfigurationManager`, but for tests you can mock `IConfigurationReader`.

It may seem overkill, but it's one time work which can be reused all over your application(s). The added benefit is, that if some day you decide to read configuration settings from somewhere else, you just change the implementation, w/o touching your consumers.

Comment: No ways is it overkill. I've just spend a few hours battling disparate config files and finally settled on abstracting the config.